# Extract dependency details from Gradle dependency tree

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am trying to extract module name of dependencies with specific group name from my project. For example, I wanted to know which springframework dependencies with group: `org.springframework.boot` is being injected into my project. Below is `build.gradle` file,

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
```

So for the group `org.springframework.boot`, my project is dependent only `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-boot-starter-web`.

I kinda of achieved this by looking from group name in runtimeClasspath. Basically checking jar path contains group name and refatoring a little bit to extarct the name of the module.

```
project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.each { element -> 
     if(element.getName().endsWith(".jar") && element.getAbsolutePath().contains("org.springframework.boot")) {
       println element.substring(0, element.getName().lastIndexOf('-'))
     }
}
```

But I am thinking is there a better way to do it? something like below where it is directly looking for group name from dependency tree. instead of searching in a string. Below code snippet, I found somewhere but able to understand what it does.

```
project.configurations
       .findAll{item -> item.canBeResolved}
       .each { item -> 
           item.incoming.afterResolve {
               resolutionResult.allComponents {
                   if(moduleVersion.group == 'org.springframework.boot') {
                      println moduleVersion.name
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague, it seems you are trying to get the "project name" of a binary dependency. Which is not a project but was build by a project. There is, unless it's embedded in the artifact, no way to determine the project name. Are you looking for artifact names perhaps?

Comment: Hi @p.streef, sorry about that. I refactor the question a little bit. Let me know if it's better. Yes, I am looking for artifact's name. But there is one special case in multi-module Gradle project where we can add other project via `implementation project(':project-name')`